My WiFi Mesh has two routers! I want to know how come the 10.xxx.xxx.xxx router shows up and how to remove it?
I have a Google Mesh WiFi router, and it works perfectly.
But when I setup a Synology NAS, it shows a two router warning:
I then did tracrt, it does show two private IP addresses:
PS C:\Users> tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to dns.google [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

192.168.86.1
modemcable001.160-233.23.mc.videotron.ca [23.233.160.1]
10.170.153.50
142.250.175.140
192.178.86.89
108.170.231.53
dns.google [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.

I think the 192.168.86.1 is the Google Mesh.
I want to know what is the 10.170.153.50 and how to get rid of it?
FWIW, all devices connected to the wifi (TVs, computers, phones, printers, etc…) are with an IP address in the 192.168.86.xxx range.

This answer may be based on some details that aren't completely proven, but based on what experience indicates seems most likely.
To me, it looks like this is likely outside your control.
What is 23.233.160.1?  It looks like reverse DNS is identifying that as modemcable001.160-233.23.mc.videotron.ca
(which, if you read that backwards, looks like a Canadian ISP named Video Tron, mc sub-domain, 23.233.160.001 cable modem).
Typically IPv4 10/8 addresses (anything starting with "10.") are private IP addresses, which respectable ISPs will drop.  However, if your ISP is using a network from 10/8 (which it is allowed to do), and the cable modem is somehow relaying (perhaps "bridging") such traffic to you, then really that confusion is only expected to affect them... and you.  Not likely to break anyone else who has a decent router/firewall to block such traffic, so most of the Internet (including upstream providers) are likely to not be affected by this.
Usually, a cable modem is sensible to think of as a demarc point (a point of demarcation, helping to separate what part of the network is yours and what is the ISPs).  Well, maybe they could argue that the cable modem is your responsibility (if you bought it), or their responsibility (if they supply it to you with a paid-for lease), and maybe they consider the point of demarcation as being something like the cable going out from your building, but since such a cable won't have an IP address itself, the cable modem is often the easy thing to think of as the point of demarcation.
So, if a device outside your network (beyond the point of demarcation) calls itself 10.170.153.50 and the ISP's equipment actually relays a response from that device to you, and that response informs you of the 10.170.153.50 network address, there's really nothing you can do to fix this, other than inform them and see if they make a change.  (One change they might make is to simply adjust the 10.170.153.50 device to not provide its IP address for the traceroute.)
It is advised that you focus on the network that is on your side of the demarcation.  If you want, you can put your own router (or compatible, e.g. a firewall device) just inside of the cable modem, and then filter out any direct traffic from 10/8, and use the entire 10/8 address range within your network however you want, and that shouldn't result in any conflicts with communications with any proper public Internet addresses.  Any internal 10/8 addresses you use shouldn't be getting beyond such a router (or outward beyond the cable modem) unless the traffic is encapsulated (e.g., using a tunnel that uses public addresses).
So, in summary: no real problem.  (Except that the ISP seems to be acting a bit lame.  You could inform them about that.  Depending on how uncool they are, they might or might not care enough to do anything about it.)
(Again: reminder: this is speculating that 23.233.160.1 is actually your cable modem, using a common type of setup that I've encounted many times before.  Your ISP's advanced technical department may be able to actually provide more precise specific details with more accuracy and less guesstimation.)

https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-23-233-160-0-1/pft?s=23.233.160.1 indicates 23.233.160.1 is used/reserved by Videotron.  It seems they are using that to provide your subscription with connectivity service.
https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-142-250-0-0-1/pft?s=142.250.175.140 indicates that 142.250.175.140 is an address used/reserved by Google.  This is probably less likely related to the idea that you're using Google Mesh equipment, and more likely related to the idea that you ping'ed 8.8.8.8 which is a Google address.

The symptom
"the system detects two or more routers in your network.
To verify this issue,  run the tracert command to check possible routes in your network.
If there is more than one hop within the private network IP range, it indicates that your PC or NAS is located behind two or more routers.
Resolution:
--Change one of the routers to bridge mode
--Configure port-forwarding on both routers independently
"
As you said, I can do nothing on the 10.xx one, neither change it to bridge nor configure port-forwarding on it.
It seams the two router problem can't be fixed?

I think what is described is more common if all private addresses (10/8, 192.168/16, 172.16/12) addresses come first, before any public addresses. Private addresses after public addresses are not so common. (Not that a person couldn't set things up like that, but routing usually doesn't occur that way, unless your ISP or beyond is exposing private addresses which I imagine is still uncommon.)  It might be helpful to understand traceroute's purpose a bit more, so it doesn't cause too much additional confusion...

Some people think of traceroute as helping to identify what device has a problem. A much better way to think of it is that traceroute helps identify what subnet gets reached, so then if a later subnet isn't reached, then the problem is usually with the device in the last subnet that was reached (failing to transmit) or the next subnet that should be reached (failing to receive). That may be presuming that devices respond nicely (publicly, even) to traceroute, which an unsafe presumption as that is not always true.

Typically, once network traffic reachins an ISP's subnet, you have no further control over the network routing, unless you also control the machines on the destination side (on the other side of whatever ISP is being used there), at which point you get control of traffic after leaving the destination's ISP subnets. Traceroute is somewhat of a common exception, as it artifically uses intentionally low "TTL" values to try to cause expiration mid-route, a technique also used by similar programs (MRT=My/Matt's Traceroute), and probably not used very commonly for other programs/purposes.
